# redirecting stdin to file

Tags: c, pipe

I want to write a program that takes whatever I type in terminal and writes it to file. Here is the code that I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int fd[2];
void pri(){
   char a[10];
   int ad=open("t.txt",O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_NONBLOCK |  O_RDWR, 0644);
   if(read(fd[0],a,10)>0){
       write(ad,a,10);
   }   
}
int main()
{
   int a;
   char s[10];
   pipe(fd);
   while(read(0,s,10)>0){
      write(fd[1],s,10);
      pri();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Currently I am using arrays and a pipe for achieving this. Is there any way that I can achieve the same without using any arrays?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how pipes and standard input/output works. Perhaps you can elaborate on the *actual* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to redirect standard *input* to *write* to a file?

Comment: have you checked the return code from `dup2`?

Comment: You've opened `t.txt` indirectly with `O_RDONLY` (read-only) mode — classically, that's 0 so omitting both `O_WRONLY` and `O_RDWR` is equivalent to specifying `O_RDONLY`.  Therefore, you've got problems writing to the file.  But there are also other conceptual problems, notably "what is writing to the pipe" (to which the short answer is "nothing").  With nothing writing to the pipe, but the write end of the pipe still open, the read will hang indefinitely.  The `dup2()` call only serves to further confuse things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was checking how to redirect the standard input to a file so that later I can use the same to redirect between terminals.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So whatever I type in terminal is not accepted as input to pipe?

Comment: No; the program no longer has a connection to the original standard input.  The standard input is now coming from the write end of the pipe, but nothing is writing to that.  Your plumbing is pretty hopelessly confused, and you're not checking the status of the `write()` calls so you won't know that they fail (though you won't even get to them because the read is blocked).  It really isn't clear what you're trying to do.  What is clear is that this is not the correct way to achieve it.

Comment: Also, with `O_CREAT` in the flags to `open()`, you need to provide a third argument — the permissions to be used in creating the file. The octal value `0644` is a moderately good value to use; `0444` is also good if the user won't need to modify the file normally. The classic `0666` is not really a good idea these days — it wasn't a good idea in the past, either, though it was hallowed by tradition; these days, risking the creation of publicly writable files is almost invariably a bad idea. (I know about [`umask`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html).)

Comment: Based on the comments, I revised the program and question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to write a program that takes whatever I type in terminal and writes it to file.

That's actually very simple and you don't need a pipe for this. (Your application itself takes the role of the pipe.)

This is what I did to demonstrate this: `mycat.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: No output file!\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mycat FILE\n");
    return 1;
  }
  FILE *fOut = fopen(argv[1], "w");
  if (!fOut) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Cannot open file '%s' for writing!", argv[1]);
  }
  int c;
  while ((c = getc(stdin)) >= 0) {
    if (putc(c, fOut) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Cannot write to file '%s'!", argv[1]);
    }
  }
  if (fclose(fOut)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Cannot write to file '%s'!", argv[1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It reads a character from `stdin` and writes it to the file stream `fOut` which has been opened by `fopen()` before. This is repeated until `getc()` fails which might happen e.g. due to end of input.

Sample session in bash on Cygwin/Windows 10:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.4.0

$ gcc -std=c11 -o mycat mycat.c

$ ./mycat
ERROR: No output file!
Usage: mycat FILE

$ ./mycat mycat.txt
Hello World.
tip tip tip
```

At this point, I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to signal `bash` the end of input.

```
$ cat mycat.txt
Hello World.
tip tip tip

$
```

I used `cat` to output the contents of `mycat.txt`. It is what typed in before (as expected).

`cat` was actually my first idea when I read the question but then I thought: It's a question tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) (not [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)). Hence my C sample code.

For completeness, the same with `cat`:

```
$ cat >mycat.txt <<'EOF'
> Hello cat.
> key key key
> EOF

$ cat mycat.txt
Hello cat.
key key key

$
```

This remembered me that `<<'EOF'` is something interpreted by `bash`. Hence, the following works as well:

```
$ ./mycat mycat.txt <<'EOF'
Hello World.
tip tip tip
EOF

$ cat mycat.txt 
Hello World.
tip tip tip

$
```

This let me belief that `cat` works quite similar though it takes input file(s) as argument(s) and writes to `stdout` (which in turn might be re-directed when calling it in a shell). In opposition to mine, `cat` doesn't fail if no arguments are provided – it reads from `stdin` instead.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to write a program that takes whatever I type in terminal and writes it to file.* => yes it's possible, use `dup()` or `dup2()` and `close()` system call accordingly.

```
char c;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

        close(1);//so that it should not print anything on console 
        int ad=open(argv[1],O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_NONBLOCK |  O_RDWR, 0644);
        // now ad is available file descriptor which is 1
        if(ad == -1){
                perror("open");
                return 0;
        }
        while(read(0,&c,1)>0){
                write(ad,&c,1);
        //when you don't want to take any input further press ctrl+d that will first save the data
        }
        return 0;
}
```

What's the need of using `pipe` for input redirection task I mean you just want to redirect user input into file So  `pipe()` is unnecessary if this is only task because you are not doing any kind of communication b/w child or parent process.