# Unable to use files to store and read input data

Tags: c++, logic

I want to write a code using files that stores inputs data and reads it from the file input.txt. I am writing this code to parse the input data. The code runs well, giving no errors but when I view the file input.txt, it doesn't show the data that I had input. Please help.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string str;
    ofstream out("input.txt");
    getline(cin,str);
    out<<str;
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    getline(in,str);
    cout<<str;
}
```

I just realised that my computer has a problem because I tried the same code on a different computer and it works

Comment: "_The code runs well, giving no errors_" You didn't check for any failure though: so, of course, it didn't show any errors. For example: you didn't check if any file opened successfully, or whether `getline` succeeded.

Comment: You should close the file stream before reopening it for reading. Put some curly braces around your streams or call `out.close()` before you create the `ifstream`

Comment: You have two streams -- one input and one output -- open simultaneously.  Make life simpler. Close the output streadm beafore opening the input stream.

Comment: @Timo @R Sahu I did close the ofstream but the input is not saving in input.txt

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables especially when you’re importing a lot of header files which may define a lot more things than they superficially appear to.

Comment: @tadman Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for info.

Comment: Well your code doesn't show us how you close those streams. Also have you checked the state of the streams with the debugger? Those streams have [flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) that you can check, like `.good()`, `.fail()`, ...

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine on my machine as-is.

Comment: @Timo I just tried this

//code to parse input
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string str;
    ofstream out("input.txt");
    if(out.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Nay, not so";
    }
    getline(cin,str);
    out<<str;

    out.close();
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    getline(in,str);
    cout<<str;
}

Comment: Please don't post code like this in the comments. This code is helpful for everyone so please edit your question and add that code there in a code block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirecting stdin to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690102/redirecting-stdin-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

Update your function so its behavior is clear to understand. Change it to:

```
int main() 
{
    string str;
 
   {
       // Open and close the output stream in this block.
       ofstream out("input.txt");
       getline(cin,str);
       out<<str;
    }

    {
       // Mot necessary to have this block but it is symmetric.
       // Open and close the input stream in this block.
       ifstream in("input.txt");
       getline(in,str);
       cout<<str;
    }
}
```